# Relation between norms

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\{u_n\} \subset H^1_0(\Omega)$ be a Palais-Smale sequence, and $\Omega$ a smooth and bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Consider $H^1_0(\Omega)$ with the norm $$||u|| = ||\nabla u||_2$$

My question is, there exists some result that gives me the relation: $$||u_n||^2 \leq C||u_n||^2_2.$$

I think the Poincare and the immersions theorems gives me the "conversely", but not this one!
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure you can expect something like this. For instance look up Caccioppoli/Energy inequalities for elliptic/parabolic equations; they give some control like this, but there are caveats.

Comment: Sequences like $u_n(x) = \sin(\pi n x)$ are counterexamples to that claim. Without more assumptions, the desired inequality is not satisfied.

Comment: Can you give the definition of a Palais-Smale sequence? Typically, this will involve a functional $I$, do you have a specific functional in mind?

Comment: Thank you for the advices, I discovered why this inequality is satisfied in my case. Thanks for everything!